# Hangman game, my code picks a word then generates a hidden word length then picks another word after that for some reason?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

so my script should run on page load √
then generate a word √
then hide the word with a string of dashes equal to its length √
but then it picks another word to replace the first one?

Ive tried to move the hiddenword generator around in my document but without it being in the start function it wont make the string i need.

```js
var wincount = 0;
var words = ["pastry", "cat", "slime", "decomposition", "fire"];
var hiddenword = [];
var usedletters = [""];
var word;
var life = 9;
var playerwin = false;

// start function sets what all the words and numbers should be at when the game starts is 

function start() {
    usedletters = [];
    word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    life = 9;
    console.log(word)
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        hiddenword[i] = ("-");
        console.log(word)
        console.log(hiddenword)
    }
    // all of this gets the id from main document then pushes what javascript generates
    document.getElementById("win").innerHTML = (wincount);
    document.getElementById("hidden").innerHTML = (hiddenword);
    document.getElementById("used").innerHTML = ("");
    document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("9");
    document.getElementById("victory").hidden
}


start();
```

```html
  <body onload="start()" class="container">
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- victory column -->
        <div class="column">
            <div id="victory">
                <p>You have won the game!</p>
                <p>CONGRATZ</p>

                <div class="tenor-gif-embed" data-postid="9807877" data-share-method="host" data-width="100%"
                    data-aspect-ratio="1.2512562814070352"><a
                        href="https://tenor.com/view/thumbsup-anime-smile-gif-9807877">Thumbs Up Good Job GIF</a>
                    from
                    <a href="https://tenor.com/search/thumbsup-gifs">Thumbsup GIFs</a></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://tenor.com/embed.js"></script>
            </div>
            <button id="new" onclick="start()">
                <p>New Game?</p>
            </button>
            <br>
            <audio id="song" controls>
                <source src="assets/song/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
        </div>

        <!-- player input column -->
        <div class="column">

            <p>Push a letter to start</p>
            <br>
            <p>Wins</p>
            <p id="win"></p>
            <br>

            <p id="what">What word am I?</p>
            <p id="hidden"></p>

            <p>Number of guesses remaining</p>
            <p id="life"></p>

            <p>Already guessed</p>
            <p id="used"></p>
            <br>
            <script src="assets/javascript/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I really just need it to pick the first word and not select a new one.

Comment: Are you saying `word` changes? Please clarify.

Comment: yes so the original array of words to select is words[food, cat,... while the word variable is the one picked by the math

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code here that would cause `word` to change between the two calls to `console.log`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Do you call `start` more than once?

Comment: You're still not showing the code in context.  You need to include your HTML.  (i.e. a [mcve])

Comment: i added a bit more code so you can see, and no the start function is only called once in the entire document.

Comment: The code you have posted does not demonstrate the behavior you describe.  Without being able to reproduce the issue, people probably won't be able to provide an answer.  As-is, this question is not clear and will need to be closed.

Comment: ive added the html, sorry if im not showing enough im trying to avoid just posting the entire document

Comment: Pretty much everyone would appreciate that you're trying to avoid putting a large amount of code in your question.  Problem is, what you have put in the question does not contain the piece of code that's causing the error.

Comment: ok, i added more of the html and now the issue is appearing

Comment: easy.  You have `start()` in your `onload` and in the body of your script.  remove one.

Comment: also... `hiddenword = '-'.repeat(word.length)`

Comment: that fixed it perfectly, thank you. and again sorry im still newer to coding and this is my first time posting here so thank you for the assistance.